# How to pass arguments to pytest if pytest is run programmatically from another module?

Tags: python, pytest

In the following example, how do I pass `args` of `run_tests()` to `pytest.main(...)` so that I can use `args` for the test methods of `TestFooBar` in `test_module.py`?

**my_module.py**

```
def run_tests(args):
    # How do I pass parameter 'args' to pytest here.
    pytest.main(['-q', '-s', 'test_module.py::TestFooBar'])
```

**test_module.py**

```
class TestFooBar():

    # How do I get 'args' of 'run_tests()' from 'my_module.py' here.

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("args", [args])
    def test_something(args):
       assert 'foo' == args['foo']

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("args", [args])
    def test_something_else(args):
        assert 'bar' == args['bar']
```

Answer (score 7):

If you execute `pytest.main` the you are doing the equivalent to calling py.test from the command line, so the only way to pass arguments that I am aware of is via a command line parameter. For this to be possible, your parameters need to be convertable to and from string.

Basically this means creating a `conftest.py` with the following

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--additional_arguments', action='store', help='some helptext')

def pytest_configure(config):
    args = config.getoption('additional_arguments')
```

Now do something with `args`: deserialize it, make it a global variable, make it a fixture, anything you want. Fixtures from `conftest.py` will be available to the entire test.

Needless to say that your call should now include the new parameter:

```
pytest.main(['-q', '-s', '--additional_arguments', args_string, 'test_module.py::TestFooBar'])
```